# Work required to push an object inside a pressurized dome by using a piston

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, pistons

There is a large dome (pictured on the left side) with an internal pressure of 2 atmospheres.

Assume that the internal pressure of the dome will stay constant at 2 atm.

The purpose is to move an object (pictured in orange) into the dome.
Weight and friction of the object are negligible.

To the right of the object there are 2 blocks of air (10 m^3 each) at 1 atmosphere.

To move the object a piston is used.

Step 1 is compressing the air from 1 to 2 atmospheres. Calculate the work required. (isothermal compression)

This is easily solved. Here is the screenshot of the calculation. [image: solution]

[Link here to the calculator I used, change the resulting parameters from pascal to atm. It's a glitch of the website.](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/thermodynamic-processes?advanced=1&c=EUR&v=Q_adiabatic:0!J!l,W_isochoric:0!J!l,U_isothermal:0!J!l,process:4.000000000000000,molar_mass:28.965,gam:1.4,heat_capacity:20.797,name:2,temperature7:20!C,volume8:10!m3,volume7:20!m3,pressure7:1!standard_atmosphere)

Step 2 is moving the object into the dome. Calculate the work required. I can't wrap my head around this.

[image]

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you managed to solve step 1 of your question with an online tool and now struggle with step 2. Your question would be easier to read if you could edit the content of the online tool's solution into the post. Also, please add to step 2 what you have tried so far and where exactly you struggle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok I placed the solution to part 1 in the post. Part 2: I had no idea how to address the problem, that's why I posted here :)

Answer (score 1):

If the pressure in the dome stays constant at 2 atm this implies there is some pressure relief mechanism so the volume is not fixed. Therefore there is no work needed to compress the air in the system any further.

If the weight and friction of the object are negligible as well, there is also theoretically no additional work needed. Work is force x distance, you need no additional  force to move the object since it is weightless and frictionless.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! If you or someone that reads this comment could point me to a computer simulation program to replicate the problem and calculate the work I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: Well the second part you just need to use some intuition, it seems like either a trick question to me or a misprint.

Personally I used EES (Engineering Equation Solver) in college. It's pretty basic (no modeling that I recall) but it could solve simple thermodynamic problems.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply!